# Querying DBpedia for 'Wikipage disambiguates' using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I've just started working with DBpedia and SPARQL.
I want to use it as followed:

Getting an input x, I want to return the "Wikipage disambiguates" of x, where x is a possible value of  "Wikipage redirect".
In other words, I want to search all the "Wikipage disambiguates" looking for x and returning its corresponding "Wikipage disambiguates".

I want to use it on Educational organizations: http://dbpedia.org/fct/facet.vsp?iri=http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FEducationalOrganization&sid=3532&cmd=new_with_class
and on general organizations:
http://dbpedia.org/fct/facet.vsp?iri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FCompany&sid=3537&cmd=new_with_class

Therefore I wanted to ask for your help -
What is the required query I need to ask?

PS: I was searching desperately for tutorials for working with SPARQL and DBpedia and couldn't find anything that hits my goal. Can you recommend me any?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, you are looking something like:

1) Finding all redirects for a given resource: [Find redirects](http://www.s3space.com?q=select%20%2a%0Awhere%20%7B%0A?y%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects%3E%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard_University%3E%0A%7D%0Alimit%2010%0A&d=http://dbpedia.org/sparql/sparql) :

```
select ?x
where {
?x <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard_University>
}
limit 10
```

Result:

- http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_College,_Cambridge,_Massachusetts
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard_U.
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_College,_Cambridge,_MA
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/University_of_Harvard
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Haravrd
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard-Radcliffe_TV
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard_Univ.
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard_university
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Kremlin_on_the_Charles

2) [Find all wikiPageDisambiguates](http://www.s3space.com?q=select%20%2a%0Awhere%20%7B%0A%20%20?x%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageDisambiguates%3E%20?y.%0A%20%20%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/University_of_Harvard%3E%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects%3E%20?y%0A%7D%0Alimit%2010%0A&d=http://dbpedia.org/sparql/sparql) of 'X' where 'X' is one of the above :

```
select ?x ?y
where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/University_of_Harvard> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects> ?y.     
  ?x <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageDisambiguates> ?y.
}
limit 10
```

Result:

- x ->  y
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard_(disambiguation)     -> http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard_University
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/HU  -> http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard_University

You can test/save/share different queries at [s3space](http://www.s3space.com/).